# Assign value to similar objects in array - BlackJack

Tags: ruby, blackjack

So I was doing BlackJack project recently and I'm kinda stuck on Ace value procedure right now.

According to the rules player can assume that Ace can be 1 or 11, peace of cake if you have 2 cards, problem with 3 cards.

I have an array of 3 cards with 2 aces, it can be - [A, A, 9], [A, 9, A], [9, A, A]

How do I say to ruby that one of the Aces should have value  11 and another one 1? Elements of array are objects of class Card with value attribute.

UPDATE

I took one of the answers and edited it a little bit, so if I got no aces and score more than 21 I get not nil value

`def score_array
  aces, non_aces = current_cards.partition(&:ace?)
  base_value = non_aces.sum(&:value) + aces.size
  return base_value unless aces?
  score_array = Array.new(aces.size + 1) { |high_aces| base_value + 10 * high_aces }
  ace_value = score_array.select { |score| score <= 21 }.max
 end`

UPDATE 2

I've refactored method into 2 lines using one of the comments idea:

`def count_score
  @score = current_cards.sum(&:value)
  @score += 10 if score < 12 && aces?
 end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is misleading to say that there is any player choice involved in the value of aces. The value of a blackjack hand is in fact fixed strictly by rule, which is quite simple:

1. Count aces as one. Period.
2. If the total of the hand is less than 12, and the hand contains at least one ace, add 10 and mark it "soft".

That's it. No need to mess with individual card values, counting aces, or any other nonsense. Just write a simple function to return the value of the hand using the above rules.

Comment: Thanks. that was helpful, i've refactored my method into 2 lines now.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hash for the Aces.

```
cards = [{A: 1}, {A: 11}, 9]
```

Simple, key/value pairs to store additional values.

Answer (score 0):

Don't say that an Ace is a 1 or 11, as it is not really needed: do say that the value of `[A, A, 9]` is 11, 21 or 31. One easy way to do it, assuming `card.ace?` returns a boolean, and `card.value` an integer for any non-Ace:

```
def score(cards)
  aces, non_aces = cards.partition { |card| card.ace? }
  base_value = non_aces.sum { |card| card.value } + aces.size
  return (aces.size + 1).times.map { |high_aces| base_value + 10 * high_aces }
end
```

Then you can easily pick the highest score that is not over 21:

```
def hand_score(cards)
  score(cards).select { |x| x <= 21 }.max
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Let `cards` be a 3-element array, each element being `:A` (for an ace) or a digit between `2` and `10`. The player is initially dealt cards corresponding to the first two elements of `cards`. If one of those cards is an ace and the other is a 10, `:BLACKJACK` is returned and the player wins against the dealer (unless the dealer also has blackjack. Note that `[:A, 10]` trumps `[:A, 4, 6]` and `[:A, :A, 9]`).

If the first two cards do not produce `:BLACKJACK` the player has a choice of standing pat with the two cards (`:HOLD`) or can request a third card from the dealer (`:HIT`). I am therefore adding an argument `hold_or_hit` to the method that computes the total score, if the first two cards do not produce blackjack.. (Tt would perhaps be more useful for the argument to be the rules the player employs to decide between hold and hit.) If the player chooses "hit" and the sum of the three cards is less than `21`, the player can ask for another "hit", and so on. Because of the wording of the question I am assuming that here at most one hit can be requested.

Simply computing the sum of three cards is not especially useful, so I will modify the return value to more closely reflect the actual game.

```
def outcome(cards, hold_or_hit)
  return 13 if hold_or_hit == :HIT && cards.count(:A) == 3 
  first2 = cards[0,2]
  return :BLACK_JACK if first2 == [:A,10] || first2 == [10,:A]
  total(hold_or_hit == :HOLD ? first2 : cards)
end

def total(arr)
  sum_non_aces = arr.sum { |c| c == :A ? 0 : c }
  sum_non_aces +
  case arr.count(:A)
    when 0
      0
    when 1
      sum_non_aces > 10 ? 1 : 11
    else
      12
    end
  end
end
```

Note that, in `total`, if `arr.count(:A) == 2`, `12` reflects one ace `11`, the other `1`.

```
outcome [10, :A,  4], :HOLD  #=> :BLACK_JACK
outcome [ 9, :A,  4], :HOLD  #=> 20
outcome [ 9, :A,  4], :HIT   #=> 14
outcome [:A, :A,  4], :HIT   #=> 16
outcome [:A, :A,  9], :HIT   #=> 21
outcome [:A, :A,  9], :HOLD  #=> 12
outcome [ 7,  9,  6], :HOLD  #=> 16
outcome [ 7,  9,  6], :HIT   #=> 22
outcome [:A, :A, :A], :HIT   #=> 13
```